# Docker Compose Port Mapping in Github Actions

Tags: docker-compose, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a testing CI with Github Actions and Docker Compose. You can see the repository [here](https://github.com/ellioseven/github-pipeline).

I have a frontend on port 3000 which communicates with a backend on port 4000. I am using a testing library (Cypress) that launches predetermined tasks in an emulated browser against the frontend.

My docker setup works locally, however I can't seem to get the networking / port mapping working correctly in the Github runner. The frontend service can't be found on `http://localhost:3000`.

NOTE: I am using `network_mode: host` to simplify the environment.

How can I configure the Github workflow to successfully connect to the frontend application on the host network on port 3000?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: Try adding a `docker ps -a` to check the containers are still up and running.

I don't think the `network_mode: host` is required